# How to create an instance of a FileDescriptor for recording audio in Android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an app that plays audio and I would like to record at least 10 seconds of audio when playback is happening. I have checked the official documentation of the MediaRecorder class from both Google and Microsoft and I have followed every step of the recipe required when you want to record audio using that class. I have also declared all the needed permissions but I have a problem setting the output file of the MediaRecorder object I have, The documentation says I need an object of FileDescriptor in the method `mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(FileDescriptor dp)` but the constructor of that class does not accept a string for a file name, instinctively I know that if the MediaRecorder object writes audio to a file then that file name needs a name so that I can search for it later and test how the audio was recorded.
Instantiating FileDescriptor like this compiles but what about the file name?

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder(this);
//set the source of the audio
recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
//set the media encoding of the output
recorder.SetOutputFormat(Android.Media.OutputFormat.Mpeg2Ts);
//specify a file descriptor where to save the recording
//what about the file name?, It surely needs a string for the file name
FileDescriptor destination = new FileDescriptor();
recorder.SetOutputFile(destination);
//prepare the recorder
recorder.Prepare();
//start recording for 10 seconds
recorder.SetMaxDuration(10000);
//start the recording session
recorder.Start();
```

Checking how FileDescriptor is used in Java then I learnt that it can work like below due to  inheritance and stuff.

```
FileDescriptor destination = new FileOutputStream("myrecording");
//the line above does not compile for Xamarin Android
```

How can I create an instance of a FileDescriptor while passing a file name to it that I can use for searching the recorded audio?

Comment: Have you looked at the [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/main/Example_WorkingWithAudio/Example_WorkingWithAudio/RecordAudio.cs)?  `SetOutputFile` has as overload that accepts a file path

Comment: Thank You for your support for Xamarin Android related issues and God bless you.